# Am I getting ripped off by my mechanic?

Tags: ac

We've been taking our cars to a local mechanic for years. Always been treated right, they've charged us fairly and everything was great.

This year, though, we've had to take one of our cars in three times for air conditioner problems. At least the last two times, and I *think* all three times, the symptoms have been the same.

The AC stopped blowing, or only worked intermittently; the fan speed would sometimes be nice and high when we started the car, but before long it stopped blowing *almost* altogether. The AC also made a funny noise when the fan wasn't blowing hard enough, though I suppose it's possible that the noise is always there, but drowned out when the fan is blowing.

I know that the August and September problems were exactly this, and I think the April problem was the same as well.

In April, they told us it was the radiator fan, and charged us for it.

In August, they told us it was the blower resistor, and charged us for it.

Today, they're telling us it's a burned-out blower motor, and are charging us for it.

We've never been cheated by these folks and have always recommended them highly, but this seems awfully suspicious. Is it plausible that these three separate parts could cause this same problem?

Comment: what year is your car by the way. It can be a case of a bad diagonoses. An honest mechanic will not extra labour though on these parts, at least he will give some discount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would doubt that you're * intentionally* getting ripped off, and it's possible that all the parts you mention actually did need to be replace.

However, even a competent mechanic may not have the background and experience to diagnose & repair the AC system, especially in modern cars where computers & sensors come into play.

When in doubt (and after a couple of attempts, you should have doubts) it may be time to take it to a dealer, who will probably have the experience and equipment to properly diagnose the problem.